# When I tried to compile a Haskell file , error:parse error on input '#'

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, haskell-platform

I was learning how to use this SDK from https://github.com/spaceships/garbled-circuits

When I finished downloading the dependencies and tried to compile one example, the error was like parse error on input '#' 
Here is the source code where the error came from:

```
import Prelude hiding (traverse)
#ifdef DEBUG
import Debug.Trace
#else
trace :: String -> a -> a
trace = flip const
traceM :: Monad m => String -> m ()
traceM _ = return ()
#endif
```

I guess it was because the C grammar like '#ifdef' was used in a Haskell file that caused this error, but I'd already used cabal install cipher-aes128 to download this SDK's dependencies (maybe).

Comment: How did you compile the example? `#ifdef` needs `CPP` extension which is enabled in this cabal file (https://github.com/spaceships/garbled-circuits/blob/master/garbled-circuits.cabal#L48). I guess it should compile when you build this library using cabal before working on one of the examples.

Comment: I just use `ghc --make Garbler.hs`. Thanks to your help, I installed all the packages in the build-depends of the library, but it still can't work and the error information is still like `parse error on input '#'`. Excuse of my ignorance, I have no experience in using  Haskell.

Comment: Well, it seems that the best way to build an example (for example, bit-and) is to run build.sh (https://github.com/spaceships/garbled-circuits/blob/master/examples/bit-and/build.sh). This script uses cabal to install all the dependencies and build the example properly.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to run build.sh, but I copy every line of build.sh and run it one by one. After that I try `ghc --make Garbler.hs` again, but the result didn't change........:(

Comment: You don't need to run `ghc --make Garbler.hs`. Running all the lines in build.sh should create an executable in the current directory.

Comment: Sorry, would you please tell me how to run build.sh? Is there any command like `python filename.py` to do that?  I am sure What I did is wrong, as it did not create any .exe file actually ......

Answer (score 4):

Referring to the Cabal documentation,

```
extensions: CPP
```

should be added to the package description in order to enable the C pre-processor.

[Source](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#conditional-compilation)

Additionally, the language pragma:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
```

Also enables the language extension.

Comment: I added CPP in {-# LANGUAGE}, and the error information changed.GHC gave the following errors:`Failed to load interface for 'Network.BSD'. It is a member of hidden package 'network-2.6.3.2'`

Comment: Hi, can I ask what build tool you're using? Fixing this error depends on the build tool being used